# Need help identifying this Star Wars set from about 2005, white and dark red triangle ship?

Tags: set-identification, star-wars

I need help identifying this Star Wars set. It was probably released about 2005. The complete kit is about 11 inches long:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a dusty [7143](http://brickset.com/sets/7143-1/Jedi-Starfighter) from 2002, but the minifigure is not there.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I've got a whole box of lego people so I'm sure I've got the figure in there somewhere.  It's covered with the hydrogen dust of interstellar space ;)